# Java shorthand ternary operator with logical operator

Tags: java, performance

I'm pretty new to java so bear with me. I'm trying to condense some of my code and was wondering how you write a ternary operator with an && or a ||. So how would I turn the below code into a shorthand ternary operator.

```
if(homePage != null && currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath())){
    isParent = true;
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should optimize for readability, not density.

Comment: Yeah, in general it's probably better to assign to a boolean and then test the boolean, to keep your statement from becoming over-long and unreadable.  And keep in mind that a ternary is compiled no more efficiently than the equivalent if/else.

Comment: ^ true unless you are writing code that will be transferred to a client to execute (ie javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, to convert your code into a ternary you'd have to code

```
isParent = (homePage != null && currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath()))
           ? true : isParent;
```

Doing

```
isParent = (homePage != null && currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath()));
```

or

```
isParent = (homePage != null && currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath()))
            ? true : false;
```

modifies isParent on the false leg, which is not what the original code does.

Answer (score 1):

the ternary operator is meant to represent an if-else case. Your case only holds an if clause, so you don't need one. You could use one if you explicitly want to set isParent to false if it fails, i.e

```
isParent = (homePage != null &&
  currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath()))  ? true  :  false;
```

This means if the condition before the ? holds true, the first value is returned (true) else the second one is returned (false).

As per the comment below, you really reallly don't need to use ternaries for boolean assignment. This can be simplified to just:

```
    isParent = (homePage != null &&
  currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath()));
```

Comment: Always, always, always, if you find yourself writing `foo ? true : false`, just write `foo`.

Comment: Thanks @75inchpianist I appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
(homePage != null && currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath()))
        ? isParent = true
        : isParent = false;
```

I would suggest to do this in the simplest way - instead of using ternary operation

```
 isParent = (homePage != null && currentParentPage.getPath().equals(homePage.getPath()));
```

Comment: But neither is correct.  And burying an assignment inside a statement is generally poor form.

Comment: I'll use the one after the `;`.